# Objects disappearing from Java TreeSet

Tags: java

I have a class that I'd like to put in a `TreeSet`, which implements `Comparable` to sort them by priority. Here's a small segment:

```
public abstract class PacketListener implements Comparable<PacketListener> {
    public enum ListenerPriority {
        LOWEST, LOW, NORMAL, HIGH, HIGHEST
    }

    private final ListenerPriority priority; // Initialized in constructor

    // ... class body ...

    @Override
    public final int compareTo(PacketListener o) {
        return priority.compareTo(o.priority);
    }
}
```

The idea is obviously for the `TreeSet` to sort the objects by priority, allowing me to iterate through the listeners in order. However, I've discovered that, for some reason, I can't add a second `PacketListener` to the set object. After adding two different `PacketListener` objects, the size of the set remains at 1.

Should I not be using `TreeSet`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The API docs for `TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) contain this important information:

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be *consistent with equals* if it is to correctly implement the `Set` interface. [...] This is so because the `Set` interface is defined in terms of the `equals` operation, but a `TreeSet` instance performs all element comparisons using its `compareTo` (or `compare`) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal.

In other words, a `TreeSet` can accommodate multiple instances of your `PacketListener` class, but only so long as each has a different priority than all the others, so that for every pair of elements *A* and *B*, exactly one of these holds: either `A == B` or `A.compareTo(B) != 0`.

If you must accommodate multiple `PacketListener` instances with the same priority in the same collection, then you need a different type of collection.  `HashSet` is perfectly good with classes that use the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods inherited from `Object`, provided that that is indeed the desired sense of instance equality.  You could also consider a `LinkedHashSet` if you want some kind of guarantee about iteration order, or maybe a `PriorityQueue` if you want to order by priority but you are willing to use a different mechanism to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

[`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) treats two objects for which `compareTo` returns 0 to be equals. Which means you'll can never have two objects with the same priority in your tree set with your current implementation.

On way to fix your problem is to make your `compareTo` method consider all values that you care about (i.e. only objects that are actually equal return 0).

Answer (score 0):

A `Set` is a collection of unique elements. As you are using the priority to compare `PacketListener`, I assume that there are at most five instances in you `TreeSet`, one for each priority.

If the structure allows you, you can find a secondary key to compare `PacketListener`, in case they have the same priority. If you can't, then `TreeSet` is the wrong way to go.